# NoMethodError in TasksController#new undefined method `tasks', Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting an error that is particularly frustrating.

I am trying to create a 'task' that has a user ID associated with it. however when I go to create a new task in the local host I receive the following error message NoMethodError in TasksController#new
undefined method `tasks' for #

Git repo: https://github.com/BrianLobdell/emailtest

Error:

[image]

Here is my tasks controller 
        class TasksController < ApplicationController
       before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = current_user.tasks.build
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: added git repo in main text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have a `belongs_to` association in your Task model, you need to have the matching `has_many` in the User model for the `current_user.tasks` method to work.

All you need to do is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  # ...

  has_many :tasks
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In trying to replicate the code from the tutorial, i guess i literally ended up writing what they had rather than changing it to my model. Thank you so much.